# DFHJS2LS - generating Json structure from cobol copybook

Tags: json, cobol, cics, copybook

I have my output structure in COBOL - from which I try to generate to a JSON structure through DFHJS2LS - IBM tools. All the fields change to be required - this giving trouble when generating classes in .Net as all the fields are not present.

Question: How and where (in COBOL or DFHJS2LS) to define fields as optional in order to get them generated properly avoiding null pointer exception.

Comment: Couldn't you use `JSON GENERATE` in COBOL directly?

Comment: The problem is all fields in Json are required - then I have an issue when generating classes from my Json. Can DFHJS2LS  skip the required the attribut on the fields. I just want fields as optional

Comment: ? ... are all fields required (=must be specified, even if empty) or are they optional (and should be left out if empty)?

Comment: @Simon The fields are generated as required and they souldn't. That's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-ts/6.1?topic=schemas-cobol-json-schema-mapping) you can define your COBOL data items with...

```
data description OCCURS n TIMES
```

...and use mapping level 4.1 or higher and specify TRUNCATE-NULL-ARRAYS = ENABLED.  There is a reference to "structured arrays" which I take to mean you would need to do something like...

```
05  Something Occurs 1 Times.
    10  Something-Real PIC X(8).
```

...so you get...

```
"type":"array"
"maxItems":1
"minItems":0
"items":{ ... }
```

You could also specify mapping level 4.0 or higher and use...

```
data description OCCURS n TO m TIMES DEPENDING ON t
```

...to obtain...

```
   "field-name":{
               "type":"array",
               "maxItems":m
               "minItems":n
               "items":{ ... }
              }`
```

Mapping level is specified by...

```
//INPUT.SYSUT1 DD *
[...other control statements...]
MAPPING-LEVEL=4.3
[...other control statements...]
```

Comment: Hello cschneid Thanks for your answer - Actually I do have an array in cobol and the mapping is 4.3(?) - I have been told. but still gettting all fields as required. I use a Jcl to generate the Json. how can I be sure it is the 4.3 version - Shall put it in the JCL?

Comment: @RemyFale Specify `MAPPING-LEVEL=4.3` as one of the control statements you have for INPUT.SYSUT1 DD.

Comment: Do you mean like - sorry I am not that experienced:
//*
//INPUT.SYSUT1   DD MAPPING-LEVEL=4.3
but I get error on it - when I write like that

Comment: @RemyFale I've added an example to my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Lidt embarassed - got misplaced DD statement - sorry for being that disturbing :-)

Comment: I mean - I got an error

Comment: My Jcl looks like this:
//JSONGEN  JOB (XF02-00R),'JsonGen',NOTIFY=&SYSUID,
//         CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=Z,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),REGION=0M
//*
//     EXPORT SYMLIST=(HFSPATH,CNAM)
//        SET HFSPATH='/xxxxxx/XXXXXX/xxx/aaaa'
//        SET CCICS=XXXXX
//*
//PRC  JCLLIB ORDER=xxxx.xxxx.PROCLIB
//*
//DOJSON EXEC PROC=XXXXX,CNAM='sssssssssss',SINGLE=N,
//            ZZZZZ=xxxxx.xxxxx,CREQ=xxxxx,
//            ZZZZZ=xxxxx.xxxxx,CREP=xxxxx
//*
whenever I add the input.sysut1 dd* I get an error.

Comment: @RemyFale Like most computer languages, JCL is picky about its syntax.  If you don't have a `//INPUT.SYSUT1 DD *` statement, then it would seem you're running a customized PROC.  Somewhere, there *must* be a SYSUT1 DD statement for the step named INPUT in that proc.

Comment: I understand - but my problem is how I incorporate this INPUT.SYSTUT1? pls copy my example and put it in. Whereever I add it in the JCL - I get an error
//JSONGEN JOB (XF02-00R),'JsonGen',NOTIFY=&SYSUID,
// CLASS=A,MSGCLASS=Z,MSGLEVEL=(1,1),REGION=0M
//* 
// PRC JCLLIB ORDER=xxxx.xxxx.PROCLIB
//*
//DOJSON EXEC PROC=XXXXX,CNAM='sssssssssss',SINGLE=N, 
// ZZZZZ=xxxxx.xxxxx,CREQ=xxxxx, 
// ZZZZZ=xxxxx.xxxxx,CREP=xxxxx 
//*

Where shall I put this INPUT.SYSTUT1  DD* statement?

Comment: @RemyFale Your `//INPUT.SYSUT1 DD *` statement goes right after the `EXEC PROC` statement, which is continued across three physical lines.  So it goes right after `// ZZZZZ=xxxxx.xxxxx,CREP=xxxxx` on the next line.  If you're trying to do this without a working knowledge of JCL then your employer isn't doing you any favors.  And I'm out.